# readLines function with new version of R

Tags: r, user-input, rscript, readlines

My function is:

```
create_matrix <- function() {
  cat("Write the numbers of vertices: ")
  user_input <- readLines("stdin", n=1)
  user_input <- as.numeric(user_input)
  print(user_input)
  }
```

With the version 3.5.0, after i entered the data the program doesn't continue the execution. I'm calling the script directly from the console.

Comment: Can't you use `data = readLines(n=1)`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work

Comment: The *Note*  in `help("showConnections")` might be relevant: " GUI consoles (which may not have an active ‘stdin’, and if they do it may not be connected to console input)".

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean specifically?

Comment: Sorry, it continue the execution but it doesn't wait my input and it give me NA value.

Comment: Can you add some more details, in particular regarding how you "entered the data" with Rscript? If you can improve this question I'd consider attaching a bounty to it because I think it might be an interesting problem.

Comment: First of all, i launch the script named graphi.R directly from terminal with an argument (for example graphi.R -c, to create a matrix(i'm using the argparse library for that)). The function create_matrix is called and ask me the number of vertices in my console. After i entered the number it's like it's waiting for another input (like a loop). With the older version i hadn't problem, i notice that they changed something in the readLines function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit this information (with the actual code and a minimal example of a script) into the question.

Comment: I updated the question. So, i can confirm that the script works fine with the version 3.4.4_2.

Comment: The is a bug fix in R-patched concerning seekable streams and `stdin` so you may be hitting that.

Comment: See also this: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L113

Comment: Thanks for your help, i understand the problem but i don't know how to solve it. So i'm back to the previous version.

Comment: @Dr.mincode Can you post your Operating system type, version and rsession info? That should help a lot. i.e Are you on MacOSX, Windows or Unix OS. stdin has different properties across Windows and various flavors of Unix.

Comment: I'm currently on arch.

Comment: Given the answer below, it is probably worth reporting this to R-devel.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel : No, that bug fix in R-patched does not fix the problem.  But using `stdin()`  {much more expressive anyway}, does work in all versions of R (see my A below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My findings using various docker images:

- The example works fine using `R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"` from `rocker/r-ver:3.4.4`.
- The example hangs as described using `R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing"`  from `rocker/r-ver:3.5.0`.
- The example hangs as described using `R Under development (unstable) (2018-05-19 r74746) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"`  from `rocker/drd`.

It looks as if the change mentioned in the release notes for version 3.5.1 is unrelated. I have sent my findings to [r-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-May/076241.html) and will report back the outcome:

- The example works fine using `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"`
- The [bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17432) has been marked as fixed. I can assert that version `R Under development (unstable) (2018-06-02 r74838) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"` works as expected.
- This [is considered a bug](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-May/076247.html), but it's unclear how and when it will be fixed.
- A [reasonable workaround](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-May/076243.html): Send end-of-file (EOF, Ctrl-D) in addition to end-of-line.

Comment: can you share you docker script?

Comment: @Technophobe01 All the docker images are available on docker hub via the rocker project. Anything else you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks, based on the note I had presumed you had written a docker script that downloaded an image and then ran the code. If not no worries.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:  Use  `stdin()`

It works fine if you use   `stdin()` instead of "stdin" .... which we would have recommended anyway.

But probably, for back compatibility "stdin" should probably work too ((or then signal a deprecation warning and work for now)

Comment: `stdin()` works in an interactive session, but not when the script is started from the console. Your first suggestion on r-devel (send EOF / Ctrl-D) works fine.

Comment: You are right, and I was wrong above: `stdin()` is not usable in a script, just interactively.